# Wait for view to be scaled before translating it

Tags: android

I have a view that needs to be scaled `view.setScaleX()` then, after it is scaled, it needs to be translated `view.setX()`. The problem is that the computer is still scaling the image when the translation is put into effect, causing unwanted behavior. How can I make the system translate only after the scaling is done. This is connected to a scale gesture detector, so the method gets called several times a second.

```
view.setScaleX( scale );
view.setX( xCoord );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are animating you need to use the method animate.

```
 //First you animate the scaleX
 view.animate().scaleX(scale).duration(timeInMs).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }
        @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            //The here you can animate the translation
            view.animate().translationX(xCoord).setListener(null);
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. When I try running it I get an error that says 'Incompatible types. Anonymous AnimationListener cannot be converted to AnimationListener'.

Comment: Probably the import you selected is wrong, try replacing by this one.

`import android.animation.Animator;`

Comment: Ah. I had to use `Animator.AnimatorListener()` instead.

Comment: Sorry. I probably typed wrong. i will edit to fix it.